# Select subsequence that selected and unselected are the same

Tags: algorithm

We have sequence of `2N` integers. We need to determine whether it's possible to select subsequence of `N` integers, in such way that selected sequence and unselected would be the same.
For example, it's possible for `1 2 1 2 3 3`, but it's impossible for `1 2 3 3 1 2`.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: *"Any ideas how to solve that?"* What have you tried so far to solve it yourself? Btw, which language?

Comment: Show us YOUR code. Where did you get stuck exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you provided no code nor language to solve this, the best I can do is give you a pseudo-code:

The idea is to have two stacks that will be filled whether you have added a number already in one or the other inside the method posted below:

```
if (stack1 has N) {
    add N to stack2
} else {
    add N to stack1
}
```

Then take each number from each stack and

```
function/method isItPossible(arrayWithSequence) {
    //Here add the numbers in the stacks

    while (both stacks are not empty) {
        if (lastNumberInStack1 is different from lastNumberInStack2) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Then just call

```
print(isItPossible(yourSequenceHere));
```

That should print `true` or `false` according to if it was possible or not.